# Como realizar flatten com reactor?

Tags: java, kotlin

Tenho uma lista de strings, onde eu converto para um Flux. E, para cada flux, realizo um flatMap que, por sua vez, retorna uma lista. Mais para frente executo um `collectList()` que converte o flux para uma lista. Como resultado dentro do map eu tenho uma `List<List<String>>`, porém o que eu realmente quero é um List. Porém, não consegui realizar o `flatten` desse cara, e ter apenas um `List<String>` com todas os valores dentro.

```
fun getAllValues() {
    var values: List<String> = listOf("value 1", "value 2")

    values
        .toFlux()
        .flatMap { findMoreValues() }
        .collectList()
        .map { /* Aqui possuo um List<List<String>> */ }
}


fun findMoreValues(): List<String> {
    callExternalApi() // retorna por exemplo listOf("value 3", "value 4")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode transformar um `List<String>` em um `Flux<String>` com:

`flatMap` + `fromIterable`:

```
values
    .toFlux()
    .flatMap { Flux.fromIterable(findMoreValues()) }
    .collectList()
    .map { /* List<String> */ }
```

`flatMap` + `toFlux`

```
values
    .toFlux()
    .flatMap { findMoreValues().toFlux() }
    .collectList()
    .map { /* List<String> */ }
```

`flatMapIterable`:

```
values
    .toFlux()
    .flatMapIterable { findMoreValues() }
    .collectList()
    .map { /* List<String> */ }
```